# Efficient derived counts from JPA joins

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I've got a Spring Boot application where I'm using `JpaRepository`'s to access my data.

I'm having issues coming up with the most elegant and efficient solution to aggregating properties in a OneToMany scenario.

I've got the following scenario:

```
public class Item {

    @Id
    private int Id;

    /*
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<LoggedItem> loggedItems

    @JsonProperty("instances")
    public int instances() {
        return loggedItems.size();
    }

    @JsonProperty("lastRun")
    public LocalDateTime lastRun() {
        return loggedItems.stream().
            .map(LoggedItem::getExecutedAt)
            .max(LocalDateTime::compareTo)).orElse(null);

    }

    */
}
```

```
public class LoggedItem {

    @Id
    private int Id;

    LocalDateTime executedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = ""item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Item item;
}
```

I have tried without the derived columns, and instead relied on the list, but I then get duplicate rows. Yes adding the distinct keyword gets rid of these, but it still seems quite inefficient.

I've also explored the use of different `@Fetch` modes, and @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference (although these are just to prevent the infinite recursion I get when serialising)

Could anyone suggest the most appropriate approach?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? What do you mean by *derived counts*?

Comment: Why don't you create a DTO and create a query that does the count and the max date?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz , I'm trying to achieve the properties that I've commented out in my Item class

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I think that sounds reasonable. Where would I do the calculation? In the mapper?

Comment: Let the query return you the max executionTime. You can write a method in your repository with custom `@Query`.

Comment: Also Check with `Fetch` type as `LAZY`

Comment: @TanmayNaik Iterating over `Fetch` type as `LAZY` outside the Hibernate session will throw a `LazyInitializationException` exception.

Comment: "I then get duplicate rows" you mean loggedItems contains duplicates? If it does, it perhaps reflects the fact  that there **are** duplicates in your database, which you might want to avoid. If there would be clean 1:n data there should be no duplicates.